# Will Caching be useful when we need multiple items in one go

Tags: caching, redis

We are working on a ecom site, where admin can store some **configuration** on the combination of **Product-Category-manufacturer** or on **Product-Category**.

We have some reports, which can return 10000 Product's transactions (with 100-1000 unique combination of **product-category-manufacturer** ). 
In this report, we also need to use **configuration** as well.

1. One option could be to fetch configurations from the same stored    procedure for all unique Product-Category-manufacturer.
2. Another option could be to cache all these combination in some    outproc cache (like redis). And once transaction data is fetched    from stored procedure, system will pull the data from cache for all 1000    **Product-Category-Feature** combinations. But in this case, we will have to request cache 1000 times and if some of keys are not found in cache, we will have to hit database.

In fact there can be some combination where data does not exist in database. If we request for these combination, system will not find it in cache, and it will have to hit database every-time. To resolve this, we will have to form a set of all the **Product-Category-Feature** combination where there is data available in cache.

Could anybody suggest that if cache will be useful in this case?

Comment: hi, Just to be clear on the issue, if your issue is getting 1000 items at once, redis dont have issue providing that. It will be so much faster than the transactional DB. And you can have set of all the Product-Category-Feature combinations, its better as we dont need cache misses. However how big will be this full set ? and do you have any other considerations?

Answer (score 0):

We use caching mainly in 2 occasions,

1. **To Reduce latency**: Cache is closer to the client it takes less time for the resource to reach the client.
2. **To Reduce network traffic**: Most of the time we see that some resources are reusable but always fetch from original source which
       is costly and make more unnecessary traffic. Adding a cache layer
       solves this.

So to answer your question, "Will Caching be useful when we need multiple items in one go?" You have to think on the above 2 points. How much you are reusing (cache hit percentage). And cost difference between cache call and call to original source.

If your issue is getting 1000 items at once, Redis don't have issue providing that. It will be so much faster than the transnational DB. And you can have set of all the Product-Category-Feature combinations, its better as we will no have cache misses. However think about the size of the Redis DB, before you proceed.